# Deploy in Windows Server using fabric

Tags: python, windows-server-2008, django

I'm developing a Python + Django project in Linux, but the Production Server is a Windows 2008 server. I've been trying to deploy (update repo, update database, restart apache) directly from my machine using `fabric`, but so far no luck.

I've tried installing `OpenSSH` and `cygwin` (in the Windows Server) but I haven't succeded with neither.

Has anyone manage to deploy a project from a Linux machine to a Windows Server using `fabric`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using freeSSHd (http://www.freesshd.com/) to run the SSH server on Windows. After that, it is a SSH connection like any other.

Comment: There is no problem if we install cygwin or this in windows and deploy like we deploy through ssh to a linux server?